# take user input data from mvc textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My domain model has property `Keywords` of `type string`. Inside database is represented as comma separated value.

On mvc view page I'm collecting user entered keywords as every keyword inside separated textbox which will be replaced into one string value with commas between.

So I tried on inserting new record to collect keywords like this

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox(@Model.Keywords, "")
</div>
```

but on `http post` controller action this property (Keywords) is empty?
What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a form for it.

For instance:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourControllerAction", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<fieldset>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox(@Model.Keywords, "")
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</fieldset>
}
```